# Split string into 2 columns, but keep the separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a panda df I want to split into 2 columns.
The separator is a word ( actually a list of words)
The problem is that I want to keep the separator (word)

My current code looks like:

```
new_auditlog = auditlog['Description'].str.split("Modified| Reset | Rebooted | Created | Disabled",1, expand = True )
                auditlog["Action"] = new_auditlog[0]
                auditlog["Something"] = new_auditlog[1]
                auditlog.drop(columns=["Description"], inplace= True)
```

The column looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns487.png)

This should be split into 2 columns based on the separator

Problem is that the separator word is "lost, and it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soVQl.png)

It's possible to keep the separator in a normal string split.
But can you do the same in a panda dataframe to columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the `()` to keep the separators, for example:

```
df['column1'].str.split('(sep1|sep2|sep3)')
```